# How to create MoreLikeThis query for inner array in NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I want to create NEST equivalent for this json query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "fields" : ["storages.items"],
            "like" :  ["a","b"],
            "min_term_freq": 1,
            "min_doc_freq": 1
        }
    }
}
```

My model is:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public InnerStorage[] Storages { get; set; }

}

public class InnerStorage
{
    public string[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

And problem is that I couldn't find way to pass array of strings to MoreLikeThis parameters.

LikeDescriptor contains only

```
Text(string likeText)
```

and

```
Document(Func<LikeDocumentDescriptor<T>, ILikeDocument> selector)
```

And only request I can create is something like

```
 var data =
      client.Search<Data>(
        x =>
          x.Query(
            q =>
              q.MoreLikeThis(
                s =>
                  s.Fields(Field.Create("storages.items"))
                    .Like(sel => sel.Document(d => d.Document(
                      new Data(){Storages =new[]{new InnerStorage(){Items = new[] {"a", "b"}}}}
                                                       ))))));
```

It contains full Data document (but I want to pass only array of strings (Items)) and creates wrong request for like:

```
"like": [{
                "_index": null,
                "_type": "data",
                "doc": {
                    "storages": [{
                        "items": ["a", "b"]
                    }]
                }
            }]
```

Comment: What version of NEST do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more terms into like part of the query by calling fluent method `Text` for each term, just like in this example:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MoreLikeThis(mlt => mlt
            .Fields(f => f.Field(ff => ff.Title))
            .Like(l => l.Text("a").Text("b")))));
```

Hope it helps.